# What is BlueStacks unique ID?

Tags: android, bluestacks

I have installed BlueStacks on multpiple PCs which are sending requests to my server. If Phone/Tab is used, then I could get the IMEI number and detect which client is sending the request and authenticate it. But from BlueStacks, what unique identifier could I fetch? Something like MAC address of the PC on which BlueStacks is running, or something else??
Can someone please advise?

Answer (score 0):

There is a unique device id for every device and you can fetch it by using the following code:

```
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;

String uniqueId = Secure.getString(getContext().getContentResolver(),Secure.ANDROID_ID);
```